# Searchkick get all results when using pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I have the following search query for products using searchkick:

```
def index
  @filter = params[:filter].blank? ? nil : Search.find(params[:filter])

  if @filter.present?
      @products = @filter.products(set_order_column(@sort), @direction, params[:page], @per_page)
  else
      query = @query.presence || "*"

      @products = Product.search(
        query, 
        where: {
          active: true
        }, 
        page: params[:page], 
        per_page: @per_page, 
        order: [{
          "#{set_order_column(@sort)}" => "#{@direction}"
        }],
        misspellings: { distance: 2 },
        fields: fields)
  end

  @filter_product_ids = @products.map(&:id)
end
```

There is the variable filter_product_ids where I need to store all results not filtered results by @per_page. Is it possible to do that? Right now, there are results just for results @per_page.

The goal to get all the results without pagination is to get uniq values for all products used to various product categorization for filtering on the website.

Thank you for any hints, Miroslav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to put this in it's own class (service class), then

```
class ProductFilter
  attr_reader :search_params, :search_query, :pagination_params

  def initialize(search_params, search_query, pagination_params)
    @search_params = search_params
    @search_query = search_query
    @pagination_params = pagination_params
  end

  # Will return all records from searchkick, unpaginated
  def filtered_products
    Product.search(search_query, search_param_stuff)
  end

  # Will return all filtered_products & then paginate on that object
  def paginated_products
    filtered_products.records.paginate(pagination_params)
  end

  private
  def search_param_stuff
    search_params
  end
end
```

In any case, searchkick's method for pagination actually works on the searchkick records object, so you can just pull the ES query (without passing in pagination params) in one method, then paginate on the `filtered_products.records`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
params[:page], @per_page
```

and

```
page: params[:page], 
per_page: @per_page,
```

from your code.

Comment: I still need to paginate the results/pages, but at the same time I need to access array of all records (without pagination).